# How to add column to OpenCart customer list?

Tags: opencart

I use OpenCart 1.5.6.4 and 2.3

In admin panel and in customer list there is no column for Customer Id

between this place:
[image: between this place]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Opencart 2:**
You need to edit this file:

```
admin/view/template/customer/customer_list.tpl
```

1)
Find:

```
<td class="text-left"><?php if ($sort == 'name') { ?>
```

Add before it:

```
<td class="text-left">Customer ID</td>
```

2)
Find:

```
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $customer['name']; ?></td>
```

Add before it:

```
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $customer['customer_id']; ?></td>
```

**For Opencart 1:**
This file:

```
admin/view/template/sale/customer_list.tpl
```

1)
Find:

```
<td class="left"><?php if ($sort == 'name') { ?>
```

Add before it:

```
<td class="left">Customer ID</td>
```

2)
Find:

```
<td class="left"><?php echo $customer['name']; ?></td>
```

Add before it:

```
<td class="left"><?php echo $customer['customer_id']; ?></td>
```

For sort customers by their id for Opencart 2 in step 1 add this code:

```
<td class="text-left">
    <?php if ($sort == 'customer_id') { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $sort_customer_id; ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($order); ?>">Customer ID</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $sort_customer_id; ?>">Customer ID</a>
    <?php } ?>
</td>
```

instead of:

```
<td class="text-left">Customer ID</td>
```

Then open this file:

```
admin/controller/customer/customer.php
```

Find:

```
$data['sort_name'] = $this->url->link('customer/customer', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&sort=name' . $url, true);
```

Add before it:

```
$data['sort_customer_id'] = $this->url->link('customer/customer', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&sort=customer_id' . $url, true);
```

Comment: پاسخ رو ویرایش کردم. این موردم توضیح دادم.